# Different method of traversing in JSON data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, for-loop

I want to display NEWS title of different articles on my website (see screenshot for clarification) but I am not able to display it, in my browser it doesn't even display `console.log(json.length)`. I have written the code but it does not display any NEWS article title see my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json.length);

        for(var i = 0 ; i<json.length ; i++){
            $(".title").html() = json.articles[i].title;    
        }

    });
});
```

In HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                        <strong>Latest Headines</strong>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is my screenshot I want to display different NEWS article title instead of "Your news title".

[image]

Comment: @Satpal I have changed the question please remove duplicate otherwise they will block my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using `json.articles.length` instead of `json.length`. If you use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) without arugument, HTML code of your tag made empty. You must be pass html code to `.html()`. Additionally you can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function to access by index:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json.articles.length);

        for(var i = 0 ; i<json.articles.length ; i++){
            $(".title").eq(i).html(json.articles[i].title);    
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: @Mohammed Hamedani but it doesn't even display `console.log(json.length);` in console.

Comment: What's your json?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
 $(".title").html() = json.articles[i].title;
```

to

```
 $(".title").eq([i]).html(json.articles[i].title);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var domEl = '';

$.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json.length);

        for(var i = 0 ; i<json.length ; i++){
            domEl += '<li><a>' + json.articles[i].title + '</a></li>';    
        }

        $(".title").html(domEl) 

    });
});
```